# Office Online Server Not Working

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-online-server

We've been using office web apps in our SharePoint 2016 farm for over a year.  A few weeks ago it stopped working.  There weren't any updates installed and we're told there weren't any GPO updates.

I found one post on this site around WMI, but that didn't fix our error.

> WordDocumentSessionServiceWatchdog reported status for
>   WordDocumentSessionService in category 'Ping'. Reported status:
>   WordDocumentSessionService ping hit an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Were there any DNS changes related to your OWA server? You should ensure that your SPWOPI binding is still valid and if not then update it.

Notes on that:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/228588a0-a6ad-4979-a419-d0ffc41bc7e8/sharepoint-2013-wopi-office-webapps-not-opening-full-word-document-but-only-preview?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all SharePoint Server 2016 web applications use claims-based authentication. Office Online rendering and editing won’t work on SharePoint Server 2016 web applications that use classic mode authentication.

If you log on to SharePoint Server 2016 by using the System Account, you won’t be able to test the connection between SharePoint Server 2016 and Office Online Server. Log on with a different account to test the connection.

Low memory conditions can cause Office document previews to fail in Office Online.

Besides, release the existing WOPI binding in SharePoint Management Shell and renew it with this script:

```
Remove-SPWOPIBinding -All:$true

New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName *YourOfficeOnlineServerNameHere*
```